# Есть ли возможность SQL запрос с подзапросом переписать на HQL (JPQL) или Criteria API?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, hibernate-criteria

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно переписать следующий SQL запрос на HQL (JPQL) и/или Criteria API?

```
SELECT id, db, cpm, crt, action, status, rbbu, 2-rbbu-crt/db/1000 k
FROM (
  SELECT c.ID id, c.DAILY_BUDGET db, c.CPM_RATE cpm, IFNULL(SUM(r.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE),0) crt,
    c.ACTION action, c.STATUS status, (count(r2.ID) > 0) rbbu
  FROM CAMPAIGNS c
  LEFT JOIN REQUESTS r
      ON c.ID = r.CAMPAIGN_ID
         AND r.CREATION_TIME BETWEEN '2019-09-20 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2019-09-20 23:59:59.9999999'
  LEFT JOIN REQUESTS r2
      ON c.ID = r2.CAMPAIGN_ID
         AND r2.SESSION_ID = 1
         AND r2.CREATION_TIME BETWEEN '2019-09-20 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2019-09-20 23:59:59.9999999'
  WHERE c.ACTION = 'RUN'
  GROUP BY c.ID
) ORDER BY k DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Собственно, весь вопрос упирается в то, что в Hibernate нельзя использовать подзапросы в предложении FROM. Как можно обойти это ограничение?

Answer (score 2):

Я вообще не понимаю, зачем тут был изобретён подзапрос...

```
SELECT c.ID id, 
       c.DAILY_BUDGET db, 
       c.CPM_RATE cpm, 
       COALESCE(SUM(r.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE),0) crt,
       c.ACTION action, 
       c.STATUS status, 
       (count(r2.ID) > 0) rbbu,
       2-(count(r2.ID) > 0)-COALESCE(SUM(r.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE),0)/c.DAILY_BUDGET/1000 k
FROM CAMPAIGNS c
LEFT JOIN REQUESTS r
     ON c.ID = r.CAMPAIGN_ID
     AND r.CREATION_TIME BETWEEN '2019-09-20 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2019-09-20 23:59:59.9999999'
LEFT JOIN REQUESTS r2
     ON c.ID = r2.CAMPAIGN_ID
     AND r2.SESSION_ID = 1
     AND r2.CREATION_TIME BETWEEN '2019-09-20 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2019-09-20 23:59:59.9999999'
WHERE c.ACTION = 'RUN'
GROUP BY c.ID
ORDER BY k DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Дело в том, что `IFNULL` в jpql приходится переписывать в виде `WHEN...CASE...ELSE`, что довольно громоздко

Comment: @golubtsoff Ок, поправил. PS. Не знаю, кто Вас научил использовать IFNULL(), но это был плохой человек...

Comment: `(count(r2.ID) > 0) rbbu` в SQL возвращает значение 1 или 0, а в jpql - булевское значение (true/false). Как быть с этим?

Comment: Кроме того, `LIMIT 1` в jpql просто отсутствует

Comment: *(count(r2.ID) > 0) rbbu в SQL возвращает значение 1 или 0, а в jpql - булевское значение (true/false). Как быть с этим?* Если возможно неявное преобразование (плюс ноль) - использовать его. Иначе CASE. *LIMIT 1 в jpql просто отсутствует* Ну это просто - берёшь первую запись, остальные игнорируешь.

Comment: 1. Плюс ноль, увы, не работает, остаётся case.  2. Это понятно, что надо брать первую запись в списке, но весь смысл в том, чтобы не гонять большие объёмы данных. Воспользовался методом `setMaxResults(1)` при построении TypedQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо @Akina за помощь.
Вот так выглядит jpql-запрос:

```
TypedQuery<Tuple> query = session.createQuery(
    "select c as campaign, " +
        "coalesce(sum(r.campaignCpmRate), 0) as crt, " +
        "case when count(r2.id) > 0 then 1 " +
            "else 0 end as rbbu, " +
        "2 - (case when count(r2.id) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) - (coalesce(sum(r.campaignCpmRate), 0)) / c.dailyBudget / 1000 as k, " +
    "from Campaign c " +
    "left join Request r on c = r.campaign " +
        "and r.creationTime between :from and :to " +
    "left join Request r2 on c = r2.campaign " +
        "and r2.session.id = :sessionId " +
        "and r2.creationTime between :from and :to " +
    "where c.action = 'RUN' " +
    "group by c " +
    "order by k desc ",
    Tuple.class
).setMaxResults(1);
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime from = now.with(LocalTime.MIN);
LocalDateTime to = now.with(LocalTime.MAX);
query.setParameter("from", from)
    .setParameter("to", to)
    .setParameter("sessionId", 1L);
Tuple result = query.getSingleResult();
```